# Exporting Matrixes from Ruby Arrays and Visualizing

Tags: ruby, matrix, data-visualization

So, if you've ever stumbled upon the idea of visualizing an matrix, and you're in Ruby, I'm not really sure how you would go about doing this.

There are a few libraries that allow arrays of data to be ploted. But I'm looking into something rather different than what I've ever done before. If you look closely on the image I have an extremely large matrix of data that I wish to see on a different program. There is roughly 1 thousand rows and about a hundred columns.

I believe the reason why I've been having such a problem with this is not necessarily for anything that I can't do but because of what I lack and what I don't know.

I'm writing because there should be an easier solution to visualizing this. I've tried spreadsheets in CSV files and in OpenOffice .ods files. But they are inadequate for this despite being great for organizing multiple data sets.

Now, concerning the matrix. For each row, there are time periods represented by letters. For each of these time periods the first element in these arrays there are prices where time has been before.

```
prices = [[9234.5, ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's']], [9234.0, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']], (...) ]
```

I appreciate any input you might have on this. I hope to find anyone experienced on this matter because I am  definitely pretty bad at front-end and data visualization.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UIWa.png

Comment: Why are CSV and OpenOffice inadequate? In order for people to help you, it's better to give a _specific_ description of what you are trying to achieve. _not this, not that_ doesnt really get to the point of what do _do_ need.

Comment: "Data visualization" is not a sufficiently-precise term for a coding question. What do you want to know about the array? (`prices` is an array, not an instance of `Matrix`. Be precise.) Perhaps you want to know, as an example, the average values of the minimum, maximum and average values of `prices[i][1]`, taken over `i = 0,1,...,prices.size-1`. We could help with precise, unambiguous questions like that. If you say you just want a general idea of what the array looks like nobody will know what you mean.

Comment: Max, and Cary: I'm looking for ways which other people use to visualize extremely large data sets such as this array. The reason it envolves Ruby it's because I am producing them in Ruby. It has roughly 700 rows and about 70 columns. If you take each price and attribute an array of letters to that each column should contain a letter and the price should occupy the first colum of each row. I need a flexible way to change the size of each axis and see how long these letters array are for each price. Is there anything like Gnuplot or Rubyvis that can give me a better front end look of this data?

Comment: Sorry to say, I again voted to close this question for seeking an off-site resource or library. Like Cary said, this question lacks specificity. (and actively confuses the reader by referring to Matrix when those are not what are in play here) See #4 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to understand why I voted to close.

Comment: [Not hallucinating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180715/matrix-visualization-in-ruby). So you decided instead of fixing the issues, and answering the inquiries (that, note, only got repeated here: "matrix", lack of specificity), that reposting the question with _zero effort_ towards fixing the problems in your previous post is the way to go? You should note that it is the best way to [get banned from asking at Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). I'm not mad, just... warning.

Comment: @amadan, anothermh: Sorry you both. I was never trying to make you feel like that but rather use the least amount of words and be concise for a matter that I considered to be very simple. Explicit matrices using Matrix class could sure do it too. But the logic behind what this is was actually very similar and not too hard to understand. You can consider this question already closed if you wish to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my right brain is serving me well, you want to approximate the image layout you have provided with the data in the array you have provided. If so, it could be as simple as this:

```
 prices.each { |row| print "#{row}\n" }
```

All this is doing is taking each outer array element and printing it on its own row.

The result of the above looks like this:

> [9234.5, ["k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s"]]
>   [9234.0, ["a", "b", "c", "d"]]

Now, you can (and may very well want to) spend some time writing up something more sophisticated for each row, for example using an inner `#each` to go through each of the inner elements and print them in some sort of format (such as centered in five spaces, with a vertical bar on the right). But the basic idea is to print each of the outer elements on its own line. Each one of those is a row in your image.

Comment: this is actually not a bad idea. The objective is rather simple. I might just do as you said and print it on a terminal output with a few well spaced rows. I'll accept this answer as this question is not getting the attention I would like to. It was never supposed to be confusing and not too much complicated.

Comment: Even if it isn't your final solution, it's probably enough of an improvement over just printing out the arrays that you can get some work done while you're coming up with something more sophisticated.